# CSS and JS won't load even when in same directory as index.php

Tags: php, html, tags

I feel like I must be missing something very obvious, because I've never had this happen before!

I'm running a local PHP server running the following command:

```
php -S localhost:8888 index.php
```

When I go to the URL, the HTML and all the php code run just fine.

However, whenever I add a script tag to add JS in the header, I recieve the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexcepted token <

And when I attempt to add a CSS file I get this error:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/assets/style.css".

No matter whether I try and include the header by using PHP `include`:

```
<?php include("../includes/layouts/header.php"); ?>
```

Or directly adding a header and these imports in `index.php`, I always receive these errors.

My hunch was it was an issue with the directory tree. But I've even placed the CSS and JS files in the same directory as `index.php` and have added the header code to `index.php`, yet I still get these errors.

**Header code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html Public "HTML TEMPLATE">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" title="no title" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

**script.js:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

**Console log of errors:**

[image: console errors]

Adding an image of my current project structure:

[image]

Comment: You should use relative urls from the document root by adding `/` in front of the URL: `href="/path-from-doc-root/style.css"` and `src="/path-from-doc-root/script.js"` etc. That way, all links and references will work no matter what URL they are under. If that doesn't work, show us your file/folder structure.

Comment: check your jscript.js line 3 and post it.

Comment: I've added the JS code, and an image of my current project structure.

Comment: add <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> before script tag script,js

Comment: I previously had a script to include jquery. However even with an empty JS file, I'm still getting the exact same error on `script.js:3`

Comment: in script.js did you alt + a and delete it? might have some space occur it.

Comment: I can confirm there's no whitespace.

Comment: try to put header and put in 1 file and check if you missed some < on it.

Answer (score 1):

you should used `/` at the start of the path. as per your update question your path become `/public/assets/style.css`. but again i recommend you should used best way

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/assets/style.css" media="all" title="no title" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <script src="/public/assets/script.js"></script>
```

Some more information about absolute path and relative path

- If the path is built starting from the system root, it is called
  absolute.
- If the path is built starting from the current location, it is called
  relative

**The best way:** you should create base url like in config.php file

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://example.com');
```

and you can used like this

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>/styles.css" />
```

Comment: Hey Bilal. I'd updated the paths in `index.php` to  `/public/assets/style.css` and `/public/assets/script.js`, yet the issue persists.

Comment: @Alkarin you are running the server from `public/`, right ? Then `public` is your `/`, remove it from the path

Comment: @msg I am in the `public` directory when I start the php server, correct. Setting the paths to `/assets/filename` still gets me the same errors.

Comment: @BilalAhmed there is already a screenshot of the console errors in the main post. Still getting the exact same errors, same lines and all.